# Ending a sentence with "and thanks"

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, colloquialisms, email

I have a colleague who ends many emails with "and thanks". To me it sounds awkward and random, but I wonder if anyone has seen this usage before?

Examples (note particularly the third one!):

"That time will work and thanks."

"Please send over the password and thanks."

"Any ideas and thanks?"

Comment: This is just his informal email style.  He's just tacking on his gratitude for whatever it happens to be on the end of his sentence. Formally it ought to be a separate sentence:  *That time will work.  [And] thank you [for setting it up]*  or *Please send over the password.  [And] thank you [for looking it up or finding it for me or whatever]*

Comment: @Jim That sounds like an answer worth posting.  Essentially, it's not formal english or a common expression - it's just the way his friend writes his emails.  It is usually suggested that you thank someone at the end of a polite email, so this makes some sense.

Answer (score 2):

It is more common to move "thanks" to its own sentence or use a comma:

> That time will work. Thanks.
>
> That time will work, thanks.

As asfallows points out in the comments below, you could also say:

> That time will work, and thanks.

Your colleague's usage is abnormal but not strictly *wrong* in the sense that the meaning is clear. I wouldn't recommend its usage in a formal context.

Of the three examples you posted, the third is the most suspect:

> Any ideas and thanks?

The "thanks" isn't part of the question and should be moved to a different sentence.

Comment: Since 'Thanks.' is considered a grammatically and syntactically complete sentence, at least colloquially, I'd say the first two examples are just missing a comma, e.g. `That time will work, and thanks` making them compound sentences. I would say that `Any ideas and thanks?` is likewise grammatically okay, but technically semantically incorrect. It implies that the speaker is asking 1) for ideas and 2) is he should be grateful.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My point was more that ", thanks" is more common than "and thanks". I'll add a clarifying note to the answer.